# Rename image according to selected option in form?

Tags: php, html, image, forms, upload

pretty simple question. I have a select option box made in HTML when an option is selected it renames the uploaded image according to the name of the option. So when uploading the image to S3, it needs to add that to the rename. So like this:

```
$actual_image_name = $hotelDir . '-' . date("Y-m-d_H:i:s"). "_" . $size . ".".$ext;
```

Where $hotelDir is actually the room type or whatever we set it too.

Here is the list example for anyone who wants to see it.

```
<select class="typeSelect" name="roomType" id="typeSelect" required="true">
                                <optgroup label="Main Areas">
                                    <option value="ext" name="ext">Exterior</option>
                                    <option value="grm" name="grm">Guest Room</option>
                                    <option value="lby" name="lby">Lobby</option>
                                    <option value="bth" name="bth">Bathroom</option>
                                    <option value="rst" name="rst">Resturant</option>
                                    <option value="ktc" name="ktc">Kitchen</option>
                                    <option value="pol" name="pol">Pool</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Other">
                                    <option value="msc" name="msc">Miscellaneous</option>
                                </optgroup>
                            </select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking to get a $_POST variable, so use $_POST['roomType'] to retreive it. Be aware of wrong data, and you should validate you've got a proper value in there.

Answer (score 1):

like what @BeaverusIV said,add an attribute 'value' in your select option box.

```
<optgroup label="Main Areas">
<option value="ext" name="ext" value="Exterior">Exterior</option>
    /*.....*/
</optgroup>
```

after selecting and uploading, use $_REQUEST['roomType'] to retrevie it.